# How to change the color of calendar icon in date picker MUI

Tags: reactjs, colors, material-ui, material-design

does someone know how to change color of calendar icon that appears automatically inside DatePicker component from MUI library?

I tried setting color by props like this

```
<DatePicker
  label="Controlled picker"
  value={value}
  onChange={(newValue) => setValue(newValue)}
  InputAdornmentProps={{
    style: {
    "& .MuiSvgIcon-root": {
      color: "orange",
    },
   },
  }}
/>
```

My goal is to set color/background color of the calendar icon inside DatePicker component

Answer (score 0):

you're targeting the wrong element `MuiButtonBase` should do the trick

```
style: {
"& .MuiButtonBase-root": {
  color: "orange",
},
```